# Show push notification in Cordova angular mobile app Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova

I am new to Cordova. I have an existing application in which I need to add push notification capability for both android and iOS.

Using library `cordova-plugin-push-notifications`. Testing in android physical device `pushNotification` variable is undefined

```js
declare var pushNotification: any;
pushNotification.registration(
  (token: string) => {
    alert(token);
    console.log(token);
    this.token = token;
  },
  (error: string) => {
    alert('error');
    console.error('in token err: ', error);
  }
) as PushNotification
```

`pushNotification` **variable is coming as undefined**.

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobile-application",
  "displayName": “App”,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.7.2",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.39",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "compare-func": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova": "^11.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-icon": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner": "^0.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-push-notifications": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-transport-security": "0.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.9",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-router-animations": "^11.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.5",
    "pulltorefreshjs": "^0.1.22",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.20",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.41",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.2",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-vibration": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "cmstrace",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": " ",
        "ANDROID_HOST": " ",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-transport-security": {},
      "cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-push-notifications": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please guide.